# using eval in server side code on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrParent" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="<% =ResolveUrl("~/cPanel/UserView.aspx?User=")%><%# Eval("StudentUserName") %>">
                <span>
                    <%  ProfileCommon pc = new ProfileCommon();
                        pc.GetProfile(Eval("StudentUserName").ToString());
                        Response.Write(pc.FirstName + "" + pc.LastName);
                    %>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The following error

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

is coming in this part

```
<%  ProfileCommon pc = new ProfileCommon();
    pc.GetProfile(Eval("StudentUserName").ToString());
    Response.Write(pc.FirstName + "" + pc.LastName);
%>
```

Comment: @The Rock: ASP.Net's `Eval` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: Hey guys, i know i can get the value using 
    <%#  Eval("StudentUserName") %>

I want to get the FirstName and LastName of the user's profile to be printed with it also.

Comment: Thank you everyone, for such quick response. :)

Comment: @Slaks , good call. I retract my incorrect statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, thanks for the help, but i got the solution :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrParent" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rptrParent_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="<% =ResolveUrl("~/cPanel/UserView.aspx?User=")%><%# Eval("StudentUserName") %>">
                <span>
                    <asp:Literal ID="lblUserName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and in the code behind file, I wrote the following function :

```
protected void rptrParent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Literal UserName = e.Item.FindControl("lblUserName") as Literal;
        String uName = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "StudentUserName").ToString();
        ProfileCommon pc = Profile.GetProfile(uName);
        UserName.Text = pc.FirstName + " " + pc.LastName + " [ " + uName + " ]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In that context you need the full call like this:

```
<%#  Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"StudentUserName") %>
```